# Problema con getline(), debo usar getenv()?

Tags: c

Muy buenas, estoy trabajando es un práctica de la uni con C, digo esto porque le uso de getline() es impuesto, dado que lo he hecho funcionar con fgets().

Mi problema radica en la compilación de getline() dado información que encontré por internet y el ejemplo de código que nos ha dado el profesor tengo el siguiente código. Todo el trabajo está dentro de la función void, lo único que hace el main es crear el `FILE *archivo;`

```
void modArchivo(FILE *archivoLocal){
    char cadena[MAX_C]; 
    char copia[MAX_C];
    char *bufferAlmac = NULL;
    size_t tamBuff;             //Sin signo
    ssize_t datLeido;           //Con signo

    archivoLocal=fopen("info.txt","r"); 

    if(archivoLocal==NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"Error al abrir el archivo");  
    } 

    else { 
        printf("%i", getline(&bufferAlmac, &tamBuff, archivoLocal));
    }
    fclose(archivoLocal);
}
```

Tras usar el getline e intentar compilar con gcc tengo el siguiente error de salida

```
info.c:29:22: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline'; did you mean 'getenv'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         printf("%i", getline(&bufferAlmac, &tamBuff, archivoLocal));
                      ^~~~~~~
                      getenv
```

Lo he compilado con gcc en windows con mingw y desde linux también con gcc y sigo con los mismos problemas, por contra, mi profesor dice que a él sí con la versión de 2016... Está getline() en deprecated o que es lo que pasa?

Muchas gracias a todos

Nota: Hay varias cosas sin usar, dado que tengo que implementar más cosas de este ejercicio pero voy de poco en poco

Comment: Hablas de Windows y Linux como si en ambos tuvieses el mismo problema ... son plataformas completamente diferentes y lo normal es que, si respetas las reglas del lenguaje, los mensajes de error sean diferentes. `getline` debería estar disponible únicamente en Linux, dentro de la librería `stdio.h`. En Windows no te va a funcionar. Lo único que se me ocurre para que funcione en Windows es que se tire del compilador de C++ (que sí tiene implementaciones de getline) y alguna de sus sobrecargas le cuadre lo suficiente al compilador, y yo creo que ni aún así.

Comment: Si, tengo el mismo problema dado que al fin y al cabo estoy ejecutando el mismo compilador. O sea utilizando gcc  para la compilación en ambos y arroja el mismo problema. Pero la solución ha pasado por cambiar el compilador, básicamente para trabajar con este programa hice copia pega en un compilador online para evitarlo. Preferí no darle más vueltas al ver que  era cosa del compilador. Muchas gracias por la ayuda